# Using Table to iterate over two lists element by element instead of as a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

So I have two lists generated in the following fashion, I don't know if it's the most efficent way to get these, but that's beside the point right now.

```
Nlayer = 6;
n = 0;
layernumber = Table[n = n + (Mod[i, 2]), {i, 1, 2*Nlayer}]
n = 1;
interfacenumber = Table[n = n + (Mod[i, 2]), {i, 0, 2*Nlayer-1}]
```

Which returns:

```
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6}

{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7}
```

And I'm trying to get the Table function to apply the i-th value of each list to two different functions X and Y, getting a list of the same length as above. What I have right now is the following (which is incorrect, it returns a 12x12 matrix instead of a 1x12 table):

```
Table[X[i]*Y[j], {i,layernumber}, {j,interfacenumber}];
```

In other words, I want it to return the 12 values that would be computed below into a list. Later, this will be expanded well beyond 12 values and I want to just expand the initial list instead of typing this out many more times.

```
X[1]*Y[1]
X[1]*Y[2]
X[2]*Y[2]
X[2]*Y[3]
X[3]*Y[3]
X[3]*Y[4]
X[4]*Y[4]
X[4]*Y[5]
X[5]*Y[5]
X[5]*Y[6]
X[6]*Y[6]
X[6]*Y[7]
```

Thank you in advance for answers, I'm headed to bed and will respond in the morning.

Comment: try `(X/@layernumber)( Y/@interfacenumber)`?

Comment: If you _have to_ use `Table`, you can try `Table[X[layernumber[[i]]]*Y[interfacenumber[[i]]], {i, Length@layernumber} ]`

Comment: ... or `Table[X[i], {i,layernumber}] * Table[Y[j], {j,interfacenumber}]`

Comment: That last one actually seems pretty obvious in hindsight. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was provided in the comments to the question - by kglr:

```
Table[X[i], {i,layernumber}] * Table[Y[j], {j,interfacenumber}]
```

Which seems a little obvious in hindsight to just use two Table functions instead of one.
Extrapolating this to the problem I'm working on (which has some unruly matricies) also required use of the Map function, again thanks to kglr.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
layernumber = Accumulate[Mod[Range[1, 2 Nlayer], 2]];
interfacenumber = 1 + Accumulate[Mod[Range[0, 2 Nlayer - 1], 2]];
MapThread[Times, {layernumber, interfacenumber}]
Inner[X[#1]*Y[#2] &, layernumber, interfacenumber, List]
```

Comment: `MapThread[X[#1]*Y[#2] &, {layernumber, interfacenumber}]`